Unable to insert Row from my Catalyst Application
I am unable to insert Datastore rows from my Catalyst Application where I send the rowdata from my web-client to Catalyst function using Function URL. But I was able to insert rows when I send the rowdata from Postman. Can someone let me know I am unable to insert the row from my Catalyst Client?

You might have faced this issue if you have not enabled Insert Permission for the App User profile since the user scope will be used if you have logged in from your catalyst application during the insert operation.
When trying to insert a row from Postman, you would making that request from Admin scope for which the Insert option will be enabled by default.
You can add the Insert option for the App user by navigating to Catalyst Console->{Your_project}->Cloud Scale->Datastore->{Your_table}->Scopes and Permissions->Table Permissions and enable the Insert option which should resolve your issue.
You can find the official documentation for the same here.
